Regarding 212(a) (7) (A) (i) (I)
I have a question about this subject. I had been denied access and offered to sign a voluntary withdrawal. When I asked the officer if I could come back, he told me not without a visa. I am Canadian and I am wondering what I should do to resolve this. They also asked questions about me to random friends traveling to the US. My friends told me they asked about where I work what I do for a living and how they know me.
Is this normal? How can I fix this?

This is not normal. What happened? Plenty of Canadian citizens enter the US with no issues

What were you attempting to do in the U.S.?

How did they know who your random friends were, so as to interrogate them about you when they entered USA? Were these random friends travelling with you? At which border crossing did you try to enter? Is Canada your place of birth?

So me first time they put me in secondary inspection they asked me if I am muslim I said yes they ask if I pray I said yes and they ask me if I have a work… they kept me 6 hours and made me sign a paper to withdrawn my application my self under intended immigrant law.

so 3 years after, one of my friend cross the border they asked him how he know me and where I  work.

so now what can I do to fix this?

to answer your question I was traveling with my family and no friends where with me. I am born in Mali

When you were denied entry under 212(a)(7)(A)(i)(I), what passport did you show?  When did this happen?

@phoog when I tried to chek in the gate agent at the airport they don’t even give me a boarding card and they call us customs to ask why they told him he need to go to the embassy for a Visa.  Should maybe I try by ground?

it happen 2018 and canadian passport

Are you and your parents single nationality Canadians? Criminal history in or out of Canada?

@egonoegono I would get in touch with an immigration lawyer in the US (or one admitted to practice the US with offices in Canada, if they exist). If you can't afford that, you can try writing to your (federal) MP to see whether they'll help you pursue this through the Ministry of Foreign Affairs.  That you didn't even get a boarding pass is truly weird; normally, the suspicion of immigrant intent comes at the admission interview, which in Canada normally happens at preclearance, after you've received a boarding pass. If CBP told the airline not to issue the pass, something unusual is going on.

@NaveedAhmed from the comments, the asker was born in Mali so almost certainly a naturalized Canadian and possibly a dual citizen.  That should not affect one's status under US immigration law; a Canadian citizen doesn't need a visa to enter the US as a visitor, regardless of other nationalities.

@egonoegono "should I maybe try by ground?": Probably not, but maybe.  If you do you will probably be denied admission, but at least you will have a chance, if the immigration officer is sympathetic, to get some more information.  It could also make your situation worse, however, so I would be very hesitant to try it.  In addition to the red flag of not even being able to get a boarding pass, there is the red flag of your identity, or at least name, being seen as so interesting that they are asking your friends about you.  This suggests that they think you are (or might be) a serious criminal.

INA 212(a)(7)(A)(i)(I) is the reason given when you are denied entry as a nonimmigrant for failure to overcome the presumption of immigrant intent. (7)(A) is technically the ground of inadmissibility for not having proper documents to enter as an immigrant, and the reason why this ground applies is that, if you are unable to overcome the presumption of immigrant intent, you are presumed to be an immigrant, in which case you need an immigrant visa, which you obviously don't have since you were trying to enter as a nonimmigrant; therefore, you are inadmissible for not having proper documents to enter as an immigrant.
This is not a "ban", and you don't need a waiver (and immigrant intent cannot be waived anyway). Immigrant intent is determined anew each time you seek entry, and it is theoretically possible that they will let you in the next day; however, in practice, you are likely to continue to be denied entry for immigrant intent unless the circumstances that led the the first denial change.
You were allowed to voluntarily withdraw your application for admission instead of being "removed", so you do not have an INA 212(a)(9)(A)(i) ban for having been removed.
What the officer said about needing a visa is wrong. Canadian citizens are exempt from needing a visa to enter the US as a nonimmigrant in all nonimmigrant statuses other than E, K, V, or S. Having been denied entry does not change that. See 9 FAM 201.1-3(B). The underlying regulations are in 22 CFR 41.2(a) and 8 CFR 212.1(a)(1).
In fact, even if a Canadian citizen has a ban (which you don't, but even if you did), they would still not need a visa to enter in nonimmigrant statuses other than E, K, V, or S -- they would apply for a nonimmigrant waiver with I-192, but if approved they would still not need a visa.

when I tried to chek in the gate agent at the airport they don’t even give me a boarding card and they call us customs to ask why they told him he need to go to the embassy for a Visa. Should maybe I try by ground?

I can’t even get a boarding pass in the airline computer it’s says refer to Usa embassy for visa

@egonoegono how and where did you receive the information that you were being denied admission under (a)(7)(A)(I)(I)?  Normally that would happen at the immigration interview, and if you never got a boarding pass, you'd never have had an immigration interview.  If you were asked to sign a voluntary withdrawal then you must have been talking to a US immigration officer, presumably at the preclearance facility in some Canadian airport.  Normally you can't get to the preclearance area unless you have a boarding pass.

I use to always go to the Usa without a problem.

But this happen under Trump administration. Someone else told me he got the same issue and as a canadian and applied for Visa and they let him in.

Yes the gave me a boarding pass and then gave the chance to withdrawn my admission plus they said I should have come earlier there is no more flight and next time if I want to comeback I need a visa. Then 1 year after I tried and no boarding pass situation happen

@egonoegono: So you are saying that, the first time, you were denied entry, and then the second time, the airline denied you a boarding pass? What reason did the airline give, exactly?

The reason the have me Us customs did not allow us to give a boarding pass and for further information go to embassy or apply for visa
